# PSR-3: для чего нужен LoggerAwareInterface?

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, для чего нужен интерфейс `LoggerAwareInterface`, какие задачи можно решать с помощь него ? Можно пример ?

Часто в разных библиотеках, вижу интерфейсы с суффиксом `Aware` и не понимаю, что это значит ? какая семантика ?

Comment: Это просто название файла/класса, посмотрите перевод aware, надеюсь поймёте почему его могут так назвать.